# Java Bytecode Editor, after save a method modification, local var table missed, and validation failed

Tags: java, bytecode

I m using JBE make a class file modification, and after I saved my changes for a method, I found that 'local variable table' miss in the left tree view, which originally under this method. And this direct caused a runtime error for JVM.
Snapshot [Before save]
[image]
[image]
Snapshot [After save]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual classfile before and after modification? Also, what error are you getting? Note that debugging information is optional, so removing it won't cause a verifier error.

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to upload attachment?

Comment: Hello, Dears. I have already solve this problem in JDE. 1st, it is not JBE function issue. 2nd, the root cause of this problem is the java stack size is mismatched, after my update for code. I add a new 'System.out.println()' statement related opcode statement, but the original code have no this statement, 'System.out.println()', call before. So the java stack size need to be modify accordingly. The exact solution is: Modify the java stack size by +1 for this method.